# Syntax error using heredoc

Tags: php, syntax, heredoc

Below, i'm using heredoc to create an email template. I keep receiving the error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\path_to_script.php on line 149`

When I remove the code below from the php script, I don't get any errors. I am pretty new to using heredoc, so excuse my ignorance.

```
        $body = <<<EOF

            {$emailStyle}

            <p>Hello. Your new client has completed registration.</p>
            <p>An email has been automatically generated and fowarded to the client.</p>
            <hr>
            <p><strong>Client details:</strong></p>
            <p>Name: {$name}</p>
            <p>Company: {$company}</p>
            <p>Phone: {$phone}</p>
            <p>Email: {$email}</p>
            <a href="{$csvLink}" target="_blank">Download CSV here</a>
            <p>Code: {$code}</p>
            <hr>

            {$emailFooter}

EOF;
```

Comment: Do you have any whitespace following the `<<<EOF`? It must have _nothing_ following it on that line. Likewise, no whitespace should follow or precede `EOF;` on its line.

Comment: Something else is causing this. This code didn't produce any errors.

Comment: It's probably some whitespace before the closing `EOF;`. It needs to site at the start of the line.

Comment: Oh. I had a space after `EOF;`

Comment: *"Oh. I had a space after EOF;"* - Yep, that would do it. Sidenote: I copied your code as it was posted, and there was no space after it, which is why I said that it didn't produce any errors for me.

Comment: The reason heredoc is ugly...

Comment: Good call on the "should follow" - @MichaelBerkowski - I for one didn't know that (till now). I knew about "preceding" but not the "following" part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I often need to go to the official docs to see the rules, but generally I just assume HEREDOCs to be entirely intolerant of any whitespace at the start or end delimiters.

Comment: Well, this one's going into my "noted" notes, as it were - @MichaelBerkowski - I'm a "code/notes" packrat (lol) I papertrail everything. Let's just call it "reference" notes ;-)